# choose one partition but optimizer use partition list all

Tags: sql, performance, oracle11g, sql-execution-plan

I have query like this :

```
select *   from P2P_TST2.kh4rqolog t  where t.kh4ldat472 between to_date('20170121120001', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') and
   to_date('20170121130101', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
```

and table test partition day by day. i choose a single partition in my query but the optimizer use partition list all in execution plan. why ?

my table definition :

```
create table KH4RQOLOG
(
   ...
  kh4stdat472     DATE,
  kh4ldat472      DATE,
  ...     
)
partition by range (KH4LDAT472)
subpartition by list (KH4DBINSTID000)
(
  partition SYS_P2898 values less than (TO_DATE(' 2016-12-06 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
    tablespace KISHTBS
    pctfree 10
    initrans 1
    maxtrans 255
  (  ...    ),
.
.
  partition SYS_P5433 values less than (TO_DATE(' 2017-01-20 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
    tablespace KISHTBS
  ... (   ...  ),
  partition SYS_P5509 values less than (TO_DATE(' 2017-01-21 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
    tablespace KISHTBS
    ... (   ...  ),
  partition SYS_P5548 values less than (TO_DATE(' 2017-01-22 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
    tablespace KISHTBS
    ... (   ...  ),
 . 
 . 
   partition SYS_P6556 values less than (TO_DATE(' 2017-02-07 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
    tablespace KISHTBS
      ... (   ...  ),
);
-- Create/Recreate indexes 
create index ESH_KHCHID472 on KH4RQOLOG (KH4BTCHID472)
  local;
create index IDX_RQIN on KH4RQOLOG (KH4RECID470)
  local;
create index PK_KH4RQOLOG on KH4RQOLOG (KH4RECID472)
  local;
```

and the execution plan is :

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1161379669
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |           | 75186 |    24M| 23967   (1)| 00:04:
|   1 |  PARTITION RANGE SINGLE|           | 75186 |    24M| 23967   (1)| 00:04:
|   2 |   PARTITION LIST ALL   |           | 75186 |    24M| 23967   (1)| 00:04:
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL   | KH4RQOLOG | 75186 |    24M| 23967   (1)| 00:04:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   3 - filter("T"."KH4LDAT472">=TO_DATE(' 2017-01-21 12:00:01', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh2
              AND "T"."KH4LDAT472"<=TO_DATE(' 2017-01-21 13:01:01', 'syyyy-mm-dd
16 rows selected
```

Comment: It sounds like something is going wrong but it's hard to tell what it is without more information.  Can you add your table definition as well as the explain plan (generated with `explain plan for select ...;` and `select * from table (dbms_xplan.display);`.

Comment: @JonHeller i add infromation to my question . i cant use sql plus

Comment: I have similar issue with my PostgreSQL partitions, it will search all partitions if supplied condition is not explicit, like for example `date = '2017-01-01'::date` will work correctly, but `date = date_trunc('month', '2017-01-27'::date)::date` will not.

We work around this by using declared variables if possible and assigning dates that we search for in there.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński I test your solution, the cost of my query decrease but still use partition all .

Comment: @Mahsaehsani You don't need SQL\*Plus, those are regular SQL commands that can be run from any SQL program.  (But if you mean you don't have access to run any commands, that's gonna be a problem, and people can't realistically expect you to solve anything if you don't have access.)

Comment: @JonHeller the execution plan added

Answer (score 1):

Your execution plan looks correct. You are looking for data within a single day, so you have a `PARTITION RANGE SINGLE` operator. Since there is no predicate on your sub-partition column, you have a `PARTITION LIST ALL` operator.